# Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': checked => { setChecked(checked); } could not be cloned

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement `react-checkbox` **Tree component** and its running also but I am getting an error when i click on icon
backend.

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
bundle.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': checked => {
    setChecked(checked);
  } could not be cloned.
    at chrome-extension://cgibknllccemdnfhfpmjhffpjfeidjga/bundles/backend.bundle.js:1:128532
    at chrome-extension://cgibknllccemdnfhfpmjhffpjfeidjga/bundles/backend.bundle.js:1:128581
    at chrome-extension://cgibknllccemdnfhfpmjhffpjfeidjga/bundles/backend.bundle.js:1:127423
    at Object.next (chrome-extension://cgibknllccemdnfhfpmjhffpjfeidjga/bundles/backend.bundle.js:1:127528)
    at chrome-extension://cgibknllccemdnfhfpmjhffpjfeidjga/bundles/backend.bundle.js:1:126443
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at C (chrome-extension://cgibknllccemdnfhfpmjhffpjfeidjga/bundles/backend.bundle.js:1:126188)
    at chrome-extension://cgibknllccemdnfhfpmjhffpjfeidjga/bundles/backend.bundle.js:1:128332
    at chrome-extension://cgibknllccemdnfhfpmjhffpjfeidjga/bundles/backend.bundle.js:1:128234
    at chrome-extension://cgibknllccemdnfhfpmjhffpjfeidjga/bundles/backend.bundle.js:1:132605
```

How can I resolve this?